# Don't show thumbnail in upload file use primefaces

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I want don't show thumbnail when i upload images. How can i remove it ?
Example : https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-nWDNS4695Lg/UtTy3-c9y2I/AAAAAAAAArY/USGOIL43Iyg/w979-h314-no/Capture4.PNG (sr, i can't show image in here)
Anymore, i want just upload one image in one time. Clearly, when i choose file A (not click upload or cancel) and then i choose file B, i want replace file B to file A (Panel upload file just show final file choose, file B). How can i do that ? Follow example picture, it just show **$RBLX1U4.jpg** to upload or cancel

Answer (score 0):

you just use

```
               <p:fileUpload value="#{bean.file}" mode="simple"/>
```

It allows only single file upload without thumbnail of the doc.

Comment: I know **mode="simple"**, but it look simple, :d. Maybe, i must try it.

Comment: Better try to create new component like <p:fileupload> .Its possible using Primefaces components......:>)